# Handle messages received through the FCM APNs interface in cordova plugin with swift

Tags: swift, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm working on native implementation of firebase messaging service in ios. I have everything working except one last and important bit. I need to get notification data when application is closed and user pushes on notification. From firebase documentation this is straightforward:

> When your app is in the background, iOS directs messages with the
>   notification key to the system tray. A tap on a notification opens the
>   app, and the content of the notification is passed to the
>   **didReceiveRemoteNotification** callback in the **AppDelegate**.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

  // Print message ID.
  if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
    print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
  }

  // Print full message.
  print(userInfo)

  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```

How do I implement this inside cordova plugin? I don't have access to `func application`, how does cordova propagate this data down to my plugin?

Similar function in Android is simple, I just get Intent Extras from my Activity. Sadly I can't find any info about this in cordova documentation.

```
-- cordova 9.0.0
-- swift 5
```

Comment: Why not use the firebase plugin instead?

Comment: The last I checked (few weeks ago), it doesn't work with latest cordova and xcode